# Why are my green bell peppers turning brown?

Tags: vegetables, raised-beds, bell-peppers, blossom-end-rot

For some reason my bell peppers are turning brown before full maturity. How do I avoid this?

[image]
[image][image]

Comment: We just had an identical question only it involved tomatoes.  Tomatoes, peppers, potatoes ARE ALL in the same family.  This looks just like blossom end rot.  Perfect pictures.

Comment: What do you mean by blossom end rot and how do I fix it?

Comment: Did you go look at that question from last week?

Comment: Will find it. Link would have been great.

Comment: http://vegetablemdonline.ppath.cornell.edu/factsheets/Tomato_BlossRt.htm

Comment: Hi! I can't find the one @stormy is referring to, but I did find others that might be helpful, including http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1757/should-i-remove-fruits-afflicted-with-blossom-end-rot... from 2011, which is specifically about peppers. Hope you get what you need either from old or new answers, or a combination of both!

Comment: Blossom end rot is on the blossom end, though. Some of these peppers have issues on the sides (and not on the blossom end). In at least those cases, it could be a fungus or old sun damage, but I don't know what it is.